# JGit throws org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException

Tags: java, git, jgit

While I am trying to parse a commit using `RevWalk` getting following exception:

```
org.eclipse.jgit.errors.MissingObjectException: Missing unknown bdc0f0d557e437b4ae835190ebd6dd548188ec71
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.WindowCursor.open(WindowCursor.java:168) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.2.1.201812262042-r.jar!/:5.2.1.201812262042-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectReader.open(ObjectReader.java:236) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.2.1.201812262042-r.jar!/:5.2.1.201812262042-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseAny(RevWalk.java:890) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.2.1.201812262042-r.jar!/:5.2.1.201812262042-r]
    at org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevWalk.parseCommit(RevWalk.java:800) ~[org.eclipse.jgit-5.2.1.201812262042-r.jar!/:5.2.1.201812262042-r]
```

Corresponding repository seems to be fine as I browse the commits through native Git commands.
Also same code base for rev walk works fine most of the time, with same repository and other repositories.
Not sure what could be missing here. Any pointers to debug this will be helpful.

Jgit version: 5.2.1.201812262042-r

Comment: I'd try with the latest version of JGit and if it happens there as well, then report a bug at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

Comment: Now since even with upgrade of library this issue is seen, bug is reported for Jgit https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=571120

Comment: Update: Root cause of this issue was at application level. Hence, JGit bug is closed.

Comment: I hit the same problem when using git-worktree. When I changed working directory to the main worktree (with `.git/` directory, not `.git` file) it worked. Thus, I think it is JGit bug after all, since `git` command works just fine while JGit doesn't.